# Imputar columna con filtrado con una serie (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un dataframe con aproximadamente 6.000.000 de instancias. Una vez realizo un filtrado para obtener las instancias que contienen *missing values* en X columna, se me reduce a 5747. Yo tengo otro dataframe con una columna que contiene los 5747 valores que me gustaría reemplazar por los *missing values* (los números de índice no son iguales), pero no consigo. El código ejecuta pero los valores no se reemplazan. Lo estoy intentando de la siguiente manera:

`data[data['reference_unit'].isnull()]['reference_unit'] = obj['reference_unit'].values`

Es decir, me gustaría imputar las instancias con missing values del df llamado **data** con los valores que tengo en dicha columna del df llamado **obj**. ¿Alguna sugerencia de cómo podría llevarlo a cabo?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Lo que estás haciendo es únicamente filtrar el `dataframe` data, te hace falta seleccionar las "celdas" deseadas, para eso puedes utilizar el método `loc()`

Como no pusiste tus datos tuve que crear un ejemplo genérico que tendrás que adaptar a tus necesidades

Ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

#Generamos un dataframe con valores del 0-100
data = np.arange(1,101)
data = data.reshape(20,5)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data,columns=['a','b','c','d','e'])

#Generamos un segundo dataframe con valores aleatorios
data = np.random.randint(5, size=(4,5))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data,columns=['a','b','c','d','e'],index=[0,7,12,5])
```

Esto genera los siguientes `dataframe`

```
#df1
    a   b   c   d   e
0   1   2   3   4   5
1   6   7   8   9   10
2   11  12  13  14  15
3   16  17  18  19  20
4   21  22  23  24  25
5   26  27  28  29  30
6   31  32  33  34  35
7   36  37  38  39  40
8   41  42  43  44  45
9   46  47  48  49  50
10  51  52  53  54  55
11  56  57  58  59  60
12  61  62  63  64  65
13  66  67  68  69  70
14  71  72  73  74  75
15  76  77  78  79  80
16  81  82  83  84  85
17  86  87  88  89  90
18  91  92  93  94  95
19  96  97  98  99  100

#df2 (Los valores pueden cambiar porque al generarlo son aleatorios)
    a   b   c   d   e
0   0   1   4   1   0
7   1   4   4   4   0
12  4   0   1   0   0
5   2   1   0   0   1
```

Voy a seleccionar 5 elementos de la columna "a" de `df1`

```
df1.loc[df1['a']%30 == 1, 'a']
```

Nota que utilizo el método `loc()`, eso hace que en realidad seleccionemos los valores y no es únicamente un filtro.

Por último reemplazamos los valores seleccionados con la columna "a" de `df2`

```
df1.loc[df1['a']%30 == 1, 'a'] = df2['a'].values
```

Este es el resultado:

```
    a   b   c   d   e
0   0   2   3   4   5
1   6   7   8   9   10
2   11  12  13  14  15
3   16  17  18  19  20
4   21  22  23  24  25
5   26  27  28  29  30
6   1   32  33  34  35
7   36  37  38  39  40
8   41  42  43  44  45
9   46  47  48  49  50
10  51  52  53  54  55
11  56  57  58  59  60
12  4   62  63  64  65
13  66  67  68  69  70
14  71  72  73  74  75
15  76  77  78  79  80
16  81  82  83  84  85
17  86  87  88  89  90
18  2   92  93  94  95
19  96  97  98  99  100
```